# Getting jQuery's functions to run when page is loaded in a div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a site where users can log in and check on outstanding support issues they have raised with us, on this site is a page to manage per company contacts. Whilst updating the site i have started using jQuery to load sub pages so that the user doesn't get a page refresh everytime. I've started to run into problems loading my JavaScript when that subpage is loaded into a div.

**The process is as follows:**
User clicks the settings link, which loads settings.php (whole page refresh)
User clicks the 'Manage Contacts' option, which loads managecontacts.php into div#settingsph
From a select box, the user chooses the contact they wish to update, this loads that users data into div#contact_info (underneath the select box), using the option's value as a contact id to pass through to editcontact.php, which queries the db and renders it into a form for making changes to.

Once this page is loaded, i intended on using jQuery validation and an ajax function to submit the form without page refresh again. However, i can't seem to get the Javascript to load at this point. I've tried referencing the Javascript as a file in the main page `<head>` tag, as script in the `<head>` tag, as a file in editcontact.php and as script in editcontact.php, but none of these seem to load the script to hide my error labels, or submit the update.

Code: editcontact.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require  '../dbsettings.php';

header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header("content-type: application/x-javascript; charset=tis-620");
?>
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id!=''){
    if($id!='NewContact'){ //if valid id has been supplied for db retrieval
        try
        {
            $db = new PDO('mssql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBDATA, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        }
        catch(PDOException $error)
        {
            echo "<h2>Error!  " . $error->getmessage()."</h2>";
            die();
        }

        $query = "  SELECT ContactID, Surname, Forename, Phone, Email, JobTitle, MobileNumber, LeaveDate 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE CompanyID ='" . $_SESSION['companyid'] . "' AND ContactID='" . $id . "'
                    ORDER BY Forename ASC";

        foreach($db->query($query) as $contact)
        {
?>
            <!--Have tried putting the script between <script> tags here-->
            <div id="contact_update">
                <form>
                    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
                    <label for="forename">Forename(s):</label>
                    <input name="forename" id="forename" value="<?php echo $contact['Forename']; ?>" class="text-input" />
                    <label class="error" for="forename" id="forename_error">Forename is required.</label>
                    <br />
                    <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                    <input name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php echo $contact['Surname']; ?>" class="text-input" />
                    <label class="error" for="surname" id="surname_error">Surname is required.</label>
                    <br />
                    <label for="jobtitle">Job Title:</label>
                    <input name="jobtitle" id="jobtitle" value="<?php echo $contact['JobTitle']; ?>" class="text-input" />

                    <br />
                    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                    <label for="phone">Telephone: </label>
                    <input name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $contact['Phone']; ?>" class="text-input" />
                    <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">Telephone is required.</label>
                    <br />
                    <label for="mob">Mobile: </label>
                    <input name="mob" id="mob" value="<?php echo $contact['MobileNumber']; ?>" class="text-input" />

                    <br />
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $contact['Email']; ?>" class="text-input" />
                    <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">Email is required.</label>
                    <br />
                    <h3>Misc Information</h3>
                    <label for="ldate">Leave Date:</label>
                    <input name="ldate" id="ldate" value="<?php echo $contact['LeaveDate']; ?>" class="text-input" />
                    <label for="ldate" class="hint">* Leave blank if still an active user</label>

                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="button" id="update_button" />
                </form>
            </div>
<?php
        } //end of foreach

    }else{ //else a new contact is being added
?>      
            <div id="contact_add">
                <form>
                    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
                    <label for="forename">Forename(s):</label><input name="forename" id="forename" /><br />
                    <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input name="surname" id="surname" /><br />
                    <label for="jobtitle">Job Title:</label><input name="jobtitle" id="jobtitle" /><br />
                    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                    <label for="phone">Telephone: </label><input name="phone" id="phone" /><br />
                    <label for="mob">Mobile: </label><input name="mob" id="mob" /><br />
                    <label for="email">Email:</label><input name="email" id="email" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                </form>
            </div>
<?php
    }
}else{ //else page was not generated with id, possibly not using javascript - die, without allowing access
    echo 'ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN';
    die();
}
?>
```

Code: jquery.settings.js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function managecontacts() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $('input.text-input').css({backgroundColor:"#ffffe0"});
  $('input.text-input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  });
  $('input.text-input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#ffffe0"});
  });

  $(".button").click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

        var forename = $("input#forename").val();
        if (forename == "") {
      $("label#forename_error").show();
      $("input#forename").focus();
      return false;
    }

        var surname = $("input#surname").val();
        if (surname == "") {
      $("label#surname_error").show();
      $("input#surname").focus();
      return false;
    }
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
      $("label#email_error").show();
      $("input#email").focus();
      return false;
    }
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        if (phone == "") {
      $("label#phone_error").show();
      $("input#phone").focus();
      return false;
    }

        var jobtitle = $("input#jobtitle").val();
        var mobile = $("input#mob").val();
        var ldate = $("input#ldate").val();

        var dataString = 'forename=' + forename + '&surname=' + surname + '&jobtitle=' + jobtitle '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&mobile=' + mobile + '&ldate=' + ldate;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Includes/stg/contactprocess.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#contact_update').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Successfully Updated</h2>")
        .append("<p>Thank you.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/tick.png' />");
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Code: `<head>` tag for loading pages into divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function open_page(name) {
        $("#settingsph").load("Includes/stg/"+name+".php");
    }
    function open_contact(id) {
        $("#contact_info").load("includes/stg/editcontact.php?id="+id);
    }
</script>
```

Any help that can be given with regards to whether this is possible or not, or whether i need to go back to the drawing board will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laimoncijus has your answer about using the callback to run your scripting. But you can also accomplish this using jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event functionality which automatically adds event functions to elements added after the document is ready. And it's easy to implement.

Change

```
$(".button").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(".button").live('click', function() {
```

this should also work for your `focus` and `blur` events.

Comment: This does the trick, but it won't work for the .hide() event.

Comment: Can't believe i was silly enough not to just hide them using CSS, i went with this in the end. Thanks Fudgey, works a treat.

Comment: Hiya, glad you got it working, but `.hide()` isn't an event. It's contained inside the `click`, `focus` and `blur` events so it should work exactly as is. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a callback function in jQuery's load() method, which is called after content is loaded into DIV. You could use it for attaching your JS code to newly loaded form and/or content.

Comment: Thanks Laimoncijus, i'm not too sure exactly what you meant without seeing source since i'm fairly new to the jQuery API. I did some googling on your phrasing which returned an interesting result, but Fudgey's was far easier to go with in the end. I appreciate the help though. :)