# Additional function execution after upgrading jquery to 1.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I initially wrote a small ajax-based settings page for an online support system i developed, using jQuery 1.4.2 and it worked fine. However, after upgrading to 1.6.1, additional executions are being called to the functions that were only ever called once previously.

I have three menu options, each with an onclick event to load a specific page into the #settingsph div. Additional code is then called depending on the page in question. (The apache server automatically assumes .php file ext are to be used if none are defined)

```
function open_page(name) {
    $("#settingsph").load("/includes/support/stg/"+name, function(){
        if(name == "managecontacts"){
            $("#contactselect").load("/includes/support/stg/contactsel");
        }else if(name == "changepw"){
            $(change_pw(), "changepw_box");
        }else if(name == "editcompany"){
            $(company_update(), "#company_update");
        }
    });
}
```

Once loaded, a select box is presented to users, to select a contact to edit. Onchange, the following function is called.

```
function open_contact(id) {
    $("#contact_info").load("/includes/support/stg/editcontact?id="+id);
    if(id != "NewContact") {
        $(contact_update(), "#contact_update"); 
    }else{
        $(contact_add(), "#contact_add"); 
    }
}
```

Let's assume the user has decided to edit their contact information (all 3 update pages use roughly the same function, but with the variables changed to reflect the page it took information from).

```
function contact_update() {
  $('input.text-input').css({backgroundColor:"#ffffe0"});
  $('input#ldate').live('focus', function(){
    $(this).datepick({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});                                   
  });
  $("input.text-input").live('focus', function(){
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"});
  });
  $("input.text-input").live('blur', function(){                                      
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#ffffe0"});
  });
  $('.error','#contact_info').hide();

  $(".buttonupd").live('click', function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

    var forename = $("input#forename").val();
    if (forename == "") {
      $("label#forename_error").show();
      $("input#forename").focus();
      $('input#forename').css({border:"solid #aa0000"});
    }else{
      $('input#forename').css({border:""});     
    }
    var surname = $("input#surname").val();
    if (surname == "") {
      $("label#surname_error").show();
      $("input#surname").focus();
      $('input#surname').css({border:"solid #aa0000"});
    }else{
      $('input#surname').css({border:""});  
    }
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    if (phone == "") {
      $("label#phone_error").show();
      $("input#phone").focus();
      $('input#phone').css({border:"solid #aa0000"});
    }else{
      $('input#phone').css({border:""});    
    }
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    if (email == "") {
      $("label#email_error").show();
      $("input#email").focus();
      $('input#email').css({border:"solid #aa0000"});
    }else{
      $('input#email').css({border:""});    
    }
    if((forename == "") || (surname == "") || (phone == "") || (email == "")){
        return false;   
    }   
    var contactid = $("input#contactid").val();
    var jobtitle = $("input#jobtitle").val();
    var site = $("select#site option:selected").val();
    var mobile = $("input#mob").val();
    var ldate = $("input#ldate").val();
    var loginallowed = $("input[name='loginallowed']:checked").val();
    var editaddress = $("input[name='editaddress']:checked").val();
    var editcontacts = $("input[name='editcontacts']:checked").val();
    var editcompany = $("input[name='editcompany']:checked").val();
    var lognewissue = $("input[name='lognewissue']:checked").val();
    var viewallissues = $("input[name='viewallissues']:checked").val();
    var viewchangelog = $("input[name='viewchangelog']:checked").val();
    var viewdownloads = $("input[name='viewdownloads']:checked").val();
    var newissuenotify = $("input[name='newissuenotify']:checked").val();
    var closeissuenotify = $("input[name='closeissuenotify']:checked").val();
    var changelognotify = $("input[name='changelognotify']:checked").val();
    var viewsitehardware = $("input[name='viewsitehardware']:checked").val();
    var viewcompanyhardware = $("input[name='viewcompanyhardware']:checked").val();

    var dataString = 'contactid=' + contactid + '&forename=' + forename + '&surname=' + surname + '&jobtitle=' + jobtitle + '&site=' + site + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&mob=' + mobile + '&ldate=' + ldate + '&loginallowed=' + loginallowed + '&editaddress=' + editaddress + '&editcontacts=' + editcontacts + '&editcompany=' + editcompany + '&lognewissue=' + lognewissue + '&viewallissues=' + viewallissues + '&viewsitehardware=' + viewsitehardware + '&viewcompanyhardware=' + viewcompanyhardware + '&viewchangelog=' + viewchangelog + '&viewdownloads=' + viewdownloads + '&newissuenotify=' + newissuenotify + '&closeissuenotify=' + closeissuenotify + '&changelognotify=' + changelognotify;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/includes/support/stg/contactupd",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('#contact_update').html("<div id='contact_upd_msg'></div>");
        $('#contact_upd_msg').html("<h2>Contact Successfully Updated</h2>")
        .append("<p>Thank you.</p>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $('#contactselect').html("")
          $("#contactselect").load("/includes/support/stg/contactsel");
        });
      }
     });
    return false;
  });
}
```

The first time the function is executed, it is called only once and appears to be fine. However, if the above function is called a second time to perhaps update another contact, two requests are sent, updating the information twice and refreshing the select box with a list of contacts in twice. If the above function is called a third time, three requests are sent and so on until the page is completely refreshed. I reverted back to 1.4.2 and these functions are only ever executed once, regardless of how many times they're called without a page refresh.

The .live() method was introduced to me [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363020/getting-jquerys-functions-to-run-when-page-is-loaded-in-a-div) when i first wrote the system and worked well at the time since the .buttonupd does not exist in the DOM when the settings.php page is loaded, is this my problem?

Comment: It's not good idea in my opinion to attach events more than once.. attach the `click` event to `.buttonupd` only once, in the `$(document).ready()` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, you shouldn't be attaching events within a function which could be called multiple times.  Each time you call `live` within that function you are attaching a new event handler.  That's why if that method gets called 3 times, triggering the event will cause the handler to run 3 times.

Here is a stripped down example:

http://jsfiddle.net/N78MX/

Notice that every time you click, the number of words added increases by one.  This is because each click calls `live` and attaches another handler.

You can fix this by simply moving all of your `live` calls outside of your function.  Since you are using `live` it is fine to call it prior to the elements in question being created.  So the stripped down example becomes this:

http://jsfiddle.net/N78MX/1

and it works no matter how many times you click.  (obviously if this were a real page I would combine those two `live` calls, but this is just for illustration).